# Is it safe to check an object for null and in the same if-statement compare the object's property value?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

See thread title. Can I safely do something like that without worrying about a `NullReferenceException`, or is not guaranteed that those boolean expressions will be evaluated left to right?

```
// can this throw an NRE?
if (obj == null || obj.property == value)
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: While this q. is about C#, in case you ever need to do VB, it's often forgotten that VB.NET by default *does not do short-circuit evaluation* for `Or` and `And`, which may introduce hard-to-find bugs. However, the keywords `OrElse` and `AndAlso` have been introduced to support this obvious deficiency.

Comment: `OrElse` has also opened the door for a floodgate of lame jokes amongst the VB team... "Do it... `OrElse`..."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They will be evaluated left to right, guaranteed. So yes, its safe.

> The conditional-OR operator (||)
>   performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands, but only evaluates its
>   second operand if necessary.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: The only caveat would be that if there is a thread that could possibly change the value of object from non-null, to null, between the execution of the left and right evaluations. That would be a rare, yet possible, issue.

Comment: Well, it is safe in terms of expression evaluation order. However, it is not thread safe if multiple threads can access the obj variable

Comment: The question was "is not guaranteed that those boolean expressions will be evaluated left to right?".

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly safe to do. If the first expression on the left is true, then the rest isn't evaluated.

Comment: I believe your answer would be correct if it instead read: "...on the *left* is *true*, ..."

Comment: <facepalm> ;)  Thanks, maybe I need to get some "Left hand, Right hand" gloves.  And should also get my eyes tested so I don't see || as &&

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed safe. See the C# documentation for [||](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(VS.71).aspx) and [&&](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(VS.71).aspx) (which is of course the opposite, short circuiting for false).

(Regarding "x || y")

> if x is true, y is not evaluated
>   (because the result of the OR
>   operation is true no matter what the
>   value of y might be). This is known as
>   "short-circuit" evaluation.